# How to initiate rtk query inside extrareducer after particular reducer is called?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am currently using rtk-query. I have created a reducer like this.

```
onClearOrderListingFilters: state => {
        state.filters = initialorderState.filters;
        state.currentlySelectedCustomer =
            initialorderState.currentlySelectedCustomer;
        state.currentlySelectedCustomerShipSite =
            initialorderState.currentlySelectedCustomerShipSite;
    },
```

and I tried to call the query inside extra reducer after `onClearOrderListingFilters` is called.
And my query logic is here:

```
builder.addMatcher(
        action => action.type === 'orders/onClearOrderListingFilters',
        state => {
            api.endpoints.queryName.initiate({
                filterArgs: {
                    offset:0,
                    limit:  10,
                    sorting: [
                         {
                            field_name: '',
                            sort_by: '',
                        },
                    ],
                    search:  [
                                {
                                    key: '',
                                    value: '',
                                },
                          ],
                },
            });
        },
    );
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to have any side effects in a reducer - something like that is a side effect.

Usually, the recommendation would be to just store the filters in your Redux store and in your component have something like

```js
const filters = useSelector(state => state.foo.filters)
const result = useMyQuery(filers)
```

Calling `.initiate` from somewhere else would also not really help you. You need the exact argument to get the values from the cache - if you had initiated that somewhere else, you would still have to have the filters available in your component to call the hook with them.